# DOMException: The operation is insecure. html2canvas with Angular 5 and Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, html2canvas, domexception

I'm suddenly having an issue with html2canvas in Firefox. I get the following Error message:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="print-section" class="text-center">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

Component:

```
     print(): void {
       const printDiv = document.getElementById('print-section');
       if (printDiv != null) {
          html2canvas(printDiv, {scale: 2}).then((canvas: any) => {
             const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
             doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, doc.internal.pageSize.width, doc.internal.pageSize.height);
             doc.save(`etiketten_${this.week}_${this.year}.pdf`);
          });
       }
    }
```

This problem only appears in Firefox (v.59.0.2). It works with Chrome and IE. I don't know what is causing this problem because the Error appears instantly (so it's not the toDataURL() function). I even tried it with diffrent elements and content.

I've been using html2canvas in this project before and I never had this issue but I couldn't find any changes in my Versions (Angular, html2canvas etc.)

```
    {
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "2.2.0",
  "license": "",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "current-week-number": "^1.0.7",
    "datejs": "^1.0.0-rc3",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.8",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.0.31",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^4.3.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "ngx-cookie": "~1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.4.3",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/datejs": "0.0.29",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Hi, have you find way ? 
I have the same issues and in my case it's due too the firefox module : ghostery  . 
I have disabled this and it's work fine. I didn't say if issues was open.